# IIFE and variable assignment in Javascript. Do we really need an IIFE? What is going on?

Tags: javascript

Say I have this function:

```
function printFruits(fruits) {
   for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
       setTimeout( function() {
          console.log( fruits[i]);
       }, i * 1000);
   }
}

printFruits(["Lemon", "Orange", "Mango"])
```

So this returns undefined 3 times.

I can see on a high level that since variables are stored not by value but by reference inside the closure... the loop is finishing first and by the time the functions are dequeued from maybe the Event Loop... the variable is already at undefined (`fruits.length` evaluates to 3 which is too high for this array size). But why does this perform strangely... it prints "apple" 3 times.

```
function printFruits(fruits) {
       for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
           var someConstant = i;
           setTimeout( function() {
              console.log( fruits[someConstant]);
           }, someConstant * 100);
       }
    }

printFruits(["mango", "banana", "apple"])
```

Shouldn't `someConstant` be changing as well with i? Why does it seem to be 2 always?

Also this works:

```
function printFruits(fruits) {
       for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
         (function() {
            var current = i;
              setTimeout( function() {
                 console.log( fruits[current]);
              }, current * 1000);
          })();
       }
    }
```

Why is the IIFE necessary to fix this problem?

Comment: "Shouldn't someConstant be changing as well with " — That's going to throw a reference errer because you never define `someCosntant` (spelling!). If I fix that error … it doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/yegimi/1/edit?js,console Try creating real [mcve]s. Preferably with [live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Define "works". Doesn't that code display `Mango` three times…?

Comment: `someConstant` and `i` are both defined in the same scope. `someConstant` is just an alias for `i`. As such it has the same fundamental problem, even if the result is slightly different. This whole thing is a problem of *scope*. Only creating a new scope can fix the problem. Adding more variables to the same scope won't.

Comment: Edited the question to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

**2nd Example**

```js
function printFruits(fruits) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var someConstant = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(fruits[someConstant]);
    }, someConstant * 1000);
  }
}
printFruits(["Lemon", "Orange", "Mango"])
```

This logs thrice *Mango*. Because everytime the someConstant variable is created and re-initialised to i. Recollect how for loop works. i-value is increasing here till 4, checks the condition 4<3, and terminates. So the matter inside the loop executes only thrice. So the last value of someConstant defined in the printFruits functional scope is 2. So when the inner function executes someConstant, its equal to 2. So we get each time Mango.

**3rd example**

```js
function printFruits(fruits) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    (function() {
      var current = i;
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(fruits[current]);
      }, current * 1000);
    })();
  }
}

printFruits(["Lemon", "Orange", "Mango"])
```

Here the beauty of closures happening. Here its a self executing function being executed, immediately. So when i = 1, it invokes immediately. Every function has a different scope now. There is a seperate current value defined for each. So later when it executes, it recollects whats the value of 'current' when it was defined inside its scope.

Comment: *"Because everytime the someConstant variable is created and re-initialised to i."* That's not quite right. There is only a single `someConstant` variable during the whole lifetime of the program and it is created before the code is even executed. What happens is that `someConstant` simply gets assigned the current value of `i`.

Comment: @FelixKling Hi, but there is a `var someConstant`. *simply gets assigned the current value * is something that happens when we var devlare once and assigns, Should there be multiple variable creation with same name? Say for first var statement, there is a memory allocation. Next time when we do again var, what happens? Does it overwrite the allocation, and simply re-assings the value? I mean how different would the stuff be if there was no var being used.

Comment: All `var` declarations are processed before any code is executed. So `var foo = 42;` is basically the same as `var foo; /* other code */ foo = 42;`. The declaration happens *once* at the beginning of the execution. Only a single variable is ever created.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between these samples is that the `for` loop increments `i` to `3` before stopping, while the last value which is assigned to `someConstant` is `2`. Your "working" code is outputting `Mango` three times (index `2` of the array) instead of `undefined` (index `3` of the array). The general behaviour is the same.

Yes, you *do* need an IIFE, or ES6's `let` keyword instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `someConstant` never gets incremented after the last iteration. The `for()` loop sets `i = 3`, the test `i < fruits.length` fails, so the loop stops. As a result, `someConstant` is still set to `2` from the last iteration of the loop. Then all the callbacks run, so they all log `fruits[2]`, which is `Mango`.

You need the IIFE to get each iteration to save its value of `i` in the closure.